# Search by selected Item in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a product detail table having columns publisher, author, Category and Title. I would like to create a search by where i can select it to search by author, by title or by publisher. Depending on my choice I should be able to search that item. I would like to show it in my PowerBI Report.

This is the input table
[image: This is the input table]

This is the output
[image: This is output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, I made a unique id "isbn13p" in the dim_competitor_prods table. After that made a Slicer table, with columns selection, categories and isbn. Selection column contained my filter data "author, publisher, title".
After creating the Slicer table, made a relationship, one to many between dim_competitor_prods and Slicer table.
The code for Selection table is given below.

SlicerTableAuthCatTitle =
UNION(
SELECTCOLUMNS(dim_competitor_prods, "Selection", "author", "Category", dim_competitor_prods[author], "isbn",dim_competitor_prods[isbn13p]),
SELECTCOLUMNS( dim_competitor_prods, "Selection", "publisher", "Category", dim_competitor_prods[publisher], "isbn",dim_competitor_prods[isbn13p]),
SELECTCOLUMNS( dim_competitor_prods, "Selection", "title", "Category", dim_competitor_prods[title], "isbn",dim_competitor_prods[isbn13p] )
)

Then just put a filter for Selection and another for Categories in the Report.